# In $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$, $A \equiv B \iff \exists_{r \in \mathbb{Z}} ( \forall_{x \in A} (x + r \in B) ∧ \forall_{y \in B} (y - r \in A))$...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We define an equivalence relation $≡$ in the set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ as:

$$A \equiv B \iff \exists_{r \in \mathbb{Z}} ( \forall_{x \in A} (x + r \in B) ∧ \forall_{y \in B} (y - r \in A))$$

Determine $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})/_≡|$ and $∣[\mathbb{N}]_≡∣ $.

---

I know that for $r = 0$: $A = B$, for $r = 1$: $A$ and $B$ lay next to each other, have $1$ common element and both cover a part of $X$ axis that is $1$ wide. Similar facts are true for $r = 2$, $r =3$...

That would mean that: $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})/≡| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

However, I don't know what to do with $∣[\mathbb{N}]_≡∣ $.

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting "have 1 common element and both cover a part of X axis that is 1 wide."  E.g. the even positive integers and the odd positive integers are equivalent using $r=1$ but they have no common element.  Similarly, the integers 1 through 100 are equivalent to the integers 2 through 101, but they have 99 elements in common.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, there is nothing to interpret, I was simply wrong. But then can I clasify different $r$ as different equivalence classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: It is not necessarily true that $A$ and $A+1$ are one unit wide and lie next to each other: $A$ could be all of $\Bbb Z$, in which case $A+1=A$. (And in fact this is the crucial observation that lets you show that $\left|[\Bbb N]_\equiv\right|=|\Bbb N|$.)

Nor do they necessarily have one element in common. In that example they are identical and have infinitely many elements in common, and if $A=\{0\}$, $A+1=\{1\}$, and they have to element in common. Finally, no subset of $\Bbb Z$ covers a one-unit segment of the $x$-axis.

In fact the quotient has cardinalities larger than $|\Bbb N|$. I’ll point you towards one way to answer that question.

Let $\Sigma$ be the set of strictly increasing sequences in $\Bbb N$ whose first term is $1$. If $\sigma=\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Sigma$, let $$A_\sigma=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^kn_k:k\in\Bbb N\right\}\,.$$ Show that if $\sigma,\tau\in\Sigma$, and $\sigma\ne\tau$, then $A_\sigma\not\equiv A_\tau$. Conclude that

$$\left|\wp(\Bbb N)/\!\sim\right|=\left|\wp(\Bbb Z)/\!\sim\right|\ge|\Sigma|\,.$$

Then show that

$$|\Sigma|=|\wp(\Bbb N)|=|\Bbb R|$$

and deduce that $\left|\wp(\Bbb N)/\!\sim\right|=\left|\wp(\Bbb Z)/\!\sim\right|=|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118988/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-m-scott-in-mathcalp-mathbbz-a-equiv-b).

Answer (score 0):

Since the quotient map $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})/\equiv$ given by $A \mapsto [A]_\equiv$ is surjective,  $$\left|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})/\equiv\right| \leq |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})| = |\mathbb{R}|.$$

To show $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})/\equiv| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$, consider the map $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z} \cap [1,\infty)) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})/\equiv$ given by $A \mapsto [\{0\} \cup A]_\equiv$.  Show that this map is injective.

For example, $[\mathbb{N}]_\equiv = \{\mathbb{Z} \cap [r,\infty) : r \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ has cardinality $|\mathbb{Z}|$ and the only representative with minimal element $0$ is $\mathbb{N}$ itself.